Button is not clickable Shadcn/radix
I am using Shadcn combobox component. I wanted to add a button over the component in order to add the functionality of resetting the state of selected option from the combobox (a button with a 'x' icon).
I have faced an issue that the button is not clickable (does not trigger the onClick function) when clicked by a mouse.Although its clicked when i press Tab (to focus on the button) + Enter . Also the Hovering functions are triggered normally (onHover). Also the button is clickable from inside the Content menu, it just does not work inside the Popover or the div holding the Popover even if it is not overlapping with the other button.
here is the code. most of it from shadcn library i just added the new button i mentioned above
function ComboboxPopover(SearchPartProps: SearchPartProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState<Status | null>(null);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-start bg-transparent relative overflow-auto">
        <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
          <PopoverTrigger asChild >
            <Button
              variant="outline"
              size="lg"
              className={cn(
                "border-0 focus-visible:outline-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent focus-visible:ring-offset-transparent bg-red-500 hover:bg-transparent flex justify-start items-center px-2 w-40 py-0 relative pointer-events-none",
                selectedStatus
                  ? "text-foreground"
                  : "text-muted-foreground hover:text-muted-foreground"
              )}
              onMouseEnter={() => SearchPartProps.setHoverIndex(SearchPartProps.index)}
              onMouseLeave={() => SearchPartProps.setHoverIndex(0)}
            >
              {selectedStatus ? (
                <>
                  <selectedStatus.icon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0" />
                  {selectedStatus.label}
                </>
              ) : (
                <>{SearchPartProps.placeholder}</>
              )}
            </Button>
          </PopoverTrigger>
          
          {selectedStatus && SearchPartProps.focusIndex == SearchPartProps.index &&(
            <Button
              onClick={(e) => { 
                console.log("clicked")
                e.stopPropagation();
                setOpen(false); 
                setSelectedStatus(null);
              }}
              className="absolute right-0 bottom-0 -translate-x-[calc(50%-6px)] -translate-y-[calc(50%-6px)] p-1 w-[15px] h-[15px] bg-gray-200 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-gray-400 z-[60] pointer-events-auto"
              aria-label="Reset selection"
            >
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                className="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                />
              </svg>
            </Button>
          )}

          <PopoverContent
            className="p-0"
            side="bottom"
            align="start"
          >
            <Command>
              <CommandInput placeholder="Change status..." />
              <CommandList>
                <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
                <CommandGroup>
                  {statuses.map((status) => (
                    <CommandItem
                      key={status.value}
                      value={status.value}
                      onSelect={(value) => {
                        setSelectedStatus(
                          statuses.find((priority) => priority.value === value) ||
                            null
                        );
                        setOpen(false);
                      }}
                    >
                      <status.icon
                        className={cn(
                          "mr-2 h-4 w-4",
                          status.value === selectedStatus?.value
                            ? "opacity-100"
                            : "opacity-40"
                        )}
                      />
                      <span>{status.label}</span>
                    </CommandItem>
                  ))}
                </CommandGroup>
              </CommandList>
            </Command>
          </PopoverContent>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

